# Quarkus Mutiny Web Client Decode JSON safely

Tags: java, quarkus, vertx-httpclient, mutiny

I've been getting into Quarkus and trying to utilize the Mutiny Vertx WebClient. My code works but I prefer not to have to rely on unsafe/unchecked assignments which is how I've currently written the code with bodyAsJson method on HttpResponse. Is there a better way, or more standard way to decode JSON from the Mutiny Vertx client? I realize I could just call bodyAsJsonObject and return that, but I need to do processing on the data the comes back from API calls so I need to decode it to a class representing the data shape/structure.

```
package com.something.app.language;

import com.something.app.model.Language;
import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.mutiny.ext.web.client.WebClient;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class LanguageService {

    @Inject
    Vertx vertx;

    private WebClient client;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        this.client = WebClient.create(vertx);
    }

    @Timed
    public Uni<List<Language>> getLanguages() {
        return this.client
                .get(80, "somehost.com", "/languages")
                .timeout(1000)
                .send()
                .onItem()
                .transform(resp -> {
                   if (resp.statusCode() == 200) {
                       return resp.bodyAsJson(List.class);
                   } else {
                       throw new RuntimeException("");
                   }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. First, Vert.x uses Jackson under the hood, so everything that can be done with Jackson is possible.

You can use `resp.bodyAsJson(MyStructure.class)`, which would create an instance of MyStructure.

If you have a JSON Array, you can map every element to the object class.

Finally, you can implement your own *body codec* (See https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/codec/BodyCodec.html).